# Unable to connect Dart DevTool to debug session

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting following error while trying to connect devtool to debug app session.

*getDartDevelopmentServiceVersion: (-32601) Method not found*

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a couple of days ago. **I tried these methods and had no luck**:

- upgrading flutter and devtools (still on stable, just went to 1.22.6)
- doing flutter clean
- clearing the cache
- reindexing in Android Studio

Finally I noticed there was a **new release of Android Studio and upgraded it**. This seems to have resolved the issue for me.

Comment: I'm using VS code which unfortunately has not released a fix for this yet. Glad to know it works on Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

this may fix your problem temporarily, it seems there is some bugs with new feature
SWITCH channel to beta, if issue is fixed during the next week highly recommend you switch to stable.

```
flutter channel beta
flutter upgrade
```

or launch manually
with `flutter pub global run devtools`
and use a link to connect